# Save Image (took with Camera Intent) from ImageView to device (Gallery/SdCard)

Tags: android, image, imageview, gallery, android-camera-intent

I made a small application which allows to open Camera with intent and take a picture. After that i display that picture in imageView. My question is, i want to save the image which i took and which is currently then available on the imageview. How can i save the image taken and available in imageview to my gallery?  My current code is:

```
public class activity_auto extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto);

        Button btnCamera= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btnCamera) {
            //starting camera function
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        if(v.getId()==R.id.goToGPS) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(activity_auto.this, function_gps.class );
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //initialize my imageview
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
06-30 11:37:25.759 2624-3776/? E/EGL_emulation: eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
06-30 11:37:25.762 2624-3776/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 3776: eglQueryContext(1716): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-30 11:37:26.600 1613-1624/? E/RecoverySystemService: Timed out connecting to uncrypt socket
06-30 11:37:26.600 1613-1624/? E/RecoverySystemService: Failed to connect to uncrypt socket
06-30 11:37:26.665 2412-3061/? E/SystemUpdateService: Failed to call RecoverySystem.cancelScheduledUpdate
                                                      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at xae.c(:com.google.android.gms:134)
                                                          at afuw.d(:com.google.android.gms:195)
                                                          at afuw.p(:com.google.android.gms:2178)
                                                          at afuw.a(:com.google.android.gms:448)
                                                          at afuw.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:50475)
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                       Caused by: java.io.IOException: cancel scheduled update failed
                                                          at android.os.RecoverySystem.cancelScheduledUpdate(RecoverySystem.java:555)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                          at xae.c(:com.google.android.gms:134) 
                                                          at afuw.d(:com.google.android.gms:195) 
                                                          at afuw.p(:com.google.android.gms:2178) 
                                                          at afuw.a(:com.google.android.gms:448) 
                                                          at afuw.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:50475) 
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
06-30 11:37:26.666 2412-3061/? E/SystemUpdateTask: exception trying to cancel scheduled update
                                                   java.io.IOException: Failed to invoke RecoverySystem.cancelScheduledUpdate
                                                       at xae.c(:com.google.android.gms:140)
                                                       at afuw.d(:com.google.android.gms:195)
                                                       at afuw.p(:com.google.android.gms:2178)
                                                       at afuw.a(:com.google.android.gms:448)
                                                       at afuw.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:50475)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
06-30 11:37:33.447 3100-3100/com.group6.travlhoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.group6.travlhoe, PID: 3100
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.group6.travlhoe/com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.group6.travlhoe.activity_auto.onActivityResult(activity_auto.java:105)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
06-30 11:37:40.070 3243-3264/? E/AppDataSearchHelper: Couldn't find corpus 'playlists'
```

Comment: Thanks for edit, will look at those syntax in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys i found the best way to add a took picture with camera intent into your gallery:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class activity_auto extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto);

        ImageButton btnCamera= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);

        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        builder.detectFileUriExposure();
    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btnCamera) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String pictureName= getPictureName();
            File imageFile=  new File(pictureDirectory,pictureName);

            //URI weil putExtra sonst nicht mit File elementen klar kommt!
            Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.goToGPS) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(activity_auto.this, function_gps.class );
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
    private String getPictureName() {
        SimpleDateFormat tst = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String timestamp = tst.format(new Date());
        return "Rechnung"+ timestamp + ".jpg";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       // Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a lot to do.

You need Storage permsissions in manifest and runtime which is a subject on its own.

You will need to deal with External Storage to get and use the folder to write the photo and with a ContentResolver to copy the photo from where it was stored by the cammera to the folder of your app.

If you want to see the photo in the gallery you will also need to work with the MediaScannerConnection so it is catalogged and made visible to the users quickly.

I recommed you follow a few tutorial on how to do all this.

Search for *CWAC Cammera* from *Commonsware*. They have a project in Github you can checkout and if you google a bit more you should find a tutorial explaining each step of the process for that project.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile i found a tutorial which i will post in the answer seqtion. Its not working, putted the user-permission for read and write to external device also in.

Comment: Hey i did it dude, watch my answer if youre interested to know it :)

Answer (score -1):

Write this code to save image

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,bytes);
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try{
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


            imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),b,"Pics","Task5");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Write this Permission in Manifest.xml

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Go to Settings -> App -> "Your App" -> permissions. Allow camera and storage access.

Comment: I added your code, but it gives me the error log which i added to the questin any help?

Comment: I have changed the code, copy and paste it as it is and follow the instructions to give access which i mentioned above. Hope it will work.

Comment: Hey it didnt work bro, but i found another way to do it. I will edit my code with the working style. Thanks for your affort!!!

Comment: My Pleasure. Happy coding.

Comment: "Go to Settings -> App -> "Your App" -> permissions.  Allow camera and storage access." is not coding. Either say that you need to take care of runtime permissions before taking the picture or include the code